# Where can one change the submission form as a conference organizer in EasyChair?

Tags: easychair

I help organize a conference in EasyChair. I have the professional license, which [allows](https://easychair.org/licenses) me to change the submission form. Where can one change the submission form?

The [workflow page](https://easychair.org/conferences/workflow.cgi) does indeed any link to change the submission form:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can change the submission form on https://easychair.org/conferences/configure:

[image]

[image]